# hosts file to create url alias

Tags: hosts

I'm using a Mac where I've located my `webroot` folder into a Dropbox sub folder.
Everything works fine but I have a problem

```
/Dropbox/webroot
/Dropbox/webroot/site-one.com
/Dropbox/webroot/site-two.com
/Dropbox/webroot/john_shared_html/site-three.com
/Dropbox/webroot/mark_shared_html/site-four.com
```

It would be great If I could find `site-three.com` and `site-four.com`

by digit in my browser `http://localhost/site-three.com`

instead of `http://localhost/john_shared_html/site-three.com`

does exists some way to do that with hosts file or something similar?
I'm using XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Use symlinks

```
ln -s /Dropbox/webroot/john_shared_html/site-three.com /Dropbox/webroot/site-three.com
```